# Creating a script that places data on a row and continues down the table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm just after some assistance modifying an app script I'm using from a reddit post. Basically it connects to an Apple shortcut and allows me to track my expenses day to day. Everything works apart from I want the data to be placed on the row and on each new entry it goes down a row (table shown). The script at the moment uses "appendrow" but this just creates a new row right at the bottom of my sheet instead of in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
var financesheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID").getSheetByName('Sheet1');


function doGet(e) {
  
  var item = JSON.parse(e.parameters.item);
  var price = JSON.parse(e.parameters.price);
  var category = JSON.parse(e.parameters.category);
  var paymentmethod = JSON.parse(e.parameters.paymentmethod);

 financesheet.appendRow([item,price,category,paymentmethod]);
 
}
```

and I've attached a screenshot of the table I would like the data to fall into. On each entry it goes down a row.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sGkI.png)

Comment: See [this entry](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/65986137?hl=en&msgid=66448020) - use [insertRowAfter(afterPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowafterafterposition)

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. How do you run your showing script of `doGet`? 2. From `The script at the moment uses "appendrow" but this just creates a new row right at the bottom of my sheet instead of in the table.` and your provided image, I think that in your showing image, when `appendRow` is run, the value is put to row 2. Is this not your expected result? But, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet. So, can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, appologies I should have been clearer. 1. I'm unsure, I took this extract of code from the original creator of the shortcut - Google Sheets system (https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/aafe5e/update_a_google_sheet_with_your_expenses/). 2. I didn't include at the bottom of the table there is an =sum function so the next clear row is always below that when I actually want the data to display in row 2 etc... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. You answered `I'm unsure` to my question of `How do you run your showing script of doGet?`. In this case, how will you test your showing script? And, I cannot understand `I didn't include at the bottom of the table there is an =sum function so the next clear row is always below that when I actually want the data to display in row 2 etc...`. Can I ask you the detail of your question? I deeply apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Apologies. The script does work as I have tested it. 2. Please see a picture of the table here (https://pasteboard.co/xe2HBbHe9rad.png) as you can see I have a formula in the bottom cell. How do I use appendrow to place the data in row 2?